# express file upload Receiving end does not exist

Tags: node.js, express, upload

I am starting with node.js, following a book from 2017. (My node version is: 16.15) **Uploading of an image** with **express-fileupload** does not work. **console logs: "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."** I googled that but did not found a helpful hint related to node.js oder express. I think it has sth. to do with the input field – but I don't know, what I should/could change. This is the code in index.js (Requirements like path, express, file-upload are imported in index.js)

```
    app.post("/posts/store", async (req, res) => {
  let image = req.files.image;
  console.log(image);
  image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, "public/img", image.name), async (error) => {
    await BlogPost.create({
      ...req.body,
      image: "/img/" + image.name,
    });
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
```

**This is the markup from form page.** In my understanding the most important part here is the correct name, which is "image" – and I use it in the js too (see above)

```
 <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Image</label>
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="image"
                    name="image"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Maybe a source of error (?) are the form related data:

```
  <form
                  action="/posts/store"
                  method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data"
                >
```

**It would be great if someone could help me finding a way to solve the error.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the problem but try to change where you pass the path for something like this

`path.resolve(__dirname + "public/img" + image.name)`

Also I found this doc maybe it helps:

https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload